# How do I programmatically change the record inside a react-admin create component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a create component where I want one of the inputs to be from a list. The code I currently have is:

```
export const ContestCalendarCreate = (props) => {
  const createControllerHook = useCreateController(props)
  const [selectedContest, setSelectedContest] = useState<any>()
  const {
    record, // empty object, unless some values were passed in the location state to prefill the form
  } = createControllerHook

  if (selectedContest) {
    record.selectedContest = selectedContest
  }

  const selectContest = (rowRecord) => {
    record.selectedContest = rowRecord
    setSelectedContest(() => rowRecord)
  }

  const transformData = (data) => {
    data.startTimestamp = moment(data.startTimestamp).unix() * 1000
    data.opensAt = moment(data.opensAt).unix() * 1000
    data.start_timestamp = data.startTimestamp
    data.opens_at_timestamp = data.opensAt
    data.id = data.selectedContest.id
    data.contest_title = data.selectedContest.contest_title
    return data
  }
  return (
    <Create {...props} transform={data => transformData(data)} >
      <SimpleForm>
        <DateTimeInput source="startTimestamp" disabled label="Starts At" validate={[required()]} />
        <DateTimeInput source="opensAt" label="Opens At" validate={[required()]}/>
        {selectedContest ?
          <TextField record={record} source="selectedContest.contest_title" label="Contest" validate={[required()]}/>
          :
          <ReferenceManyField label="Select A Contest" reference="admin/contest" allowEmpty filter={{approved: true, states: [ContestState.unpublished]}}>
            <List filters={<ContestFilter />} bulkActionButtons={false} exporter={false} sort={{ field: 'contest_title', order: 'DESC' }} >
              <Datagrid rowClick={(id, path, rowRecord) => selectContest(rowRecord)}>
                <TextField source="contest_title" />
                <TextField source="contest_description" />
                <TextField source="quiz_title" />
                <TextField source="quiz_description" />
                <TextField source="topics" />
              </Datagrid>
            </List>
          </ReferenceManyField>
        }
        {selectedContest && <Button variant="contained" color="default" disableElevation onClick={() => selectContest(null)}>Select Another Contest</Button>}
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )
}
```

The selectContest function sort of works; however, when it executes it resets the other form inputs to their defaults.

Is there a different way for me to be changing the record that i get from the useCreateController hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question correctly  - you need to update `"selectedContest"` field in the current form on `Datagrid`'s row click event. Instead of overriding the record you can use the `react-final-form` hook `useForm` and the change method available like so:

```
const form = useForm();

// rowClick function
(id, path, rowRecord) => form.change('selectedContest', rowRecord)
```

This is explained here in the docs under the Linking Two Inputs section: [React-Admin Docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html)

Comment: Actually is not explained there but I guess it is in the final form docs

Comment: One quesiton, where should the useForm() be placed in this example?

Comment: Inside the SimpleForm component - you can extract the whole form's children to another component to do that. Or extract the DataGrid part only and then call it there.

Comment: Yeah actually I knew it from the error message (must be placed inside a Form) but could not figure out how to call useForm() without moving it to another component. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: ACtually it's not working for me, does anyone has an 2023 update?

Comment: @SimonFakir - this approach works for `react-admin` 3.xx version. v4 replaces the `final-form` package usage and the approach should be modified according the `react-hook-form` that is now used